# What's "Egbert the Egregious" and "Emeric the Evil" in the context

Tags: meaning-in-context

> "Which is that the possessor of the wand must capture it from its previous owner, if he is to be truly master of it," said Xenophilius. "Surely you have heard of the way the wand came to **Egbert the Egregious**, after his slaughter of **Emeric the Evil**? ... ..."
>
> <sub>Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows</sub>

I think Egbert and Emeric are persons' names, but I'm not sure of "the Egregious" and "the Evil". Are they their nicknames or something?

Comment: Like "[Ethelred the Unready](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%86thelred_the_Unready)" they are adjectives used to describe the person, and become their nickname.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are adjectives that have been converted to nouns and used as appellations. It is not uncommon for such appellations to be applied to people who particularly represent a specific quality. This occurs in real life as well. For instance, [Richard I of England](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard_I_of_England) is widely known as Richard the Lionheart.